# use bullet to indicate current page in navigation menu

Tags: css, navigation

I have a vertically displayed navigation menu. I would like a bullet point to appear to the left of the page currently being viewed. I've read a little bit about using background changes applied to `li` to indicate page, but I don't know how to apply that to using bullets.. Any ideas?

```
<nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="#lookbook">lookbook</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services">services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

nav {
    position: fixed;
    right: 13%;
    top: 65%;
}

nav ul li {
    text-align: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jtRws/

Comment: How do you check current page? Using #IDs on body, or with javascript checking the URL address?

Comment: @earthdesigner I use id's. EX: `<div id="about">` for `<li><a href="#about">about</a></li>`

Comment: If you wrap your `li` in a `div` you've got invalid html, which the browser will correct (possibly unpredictably).

Comment: @DavidThomas My code validates perfectly for HTML5 when checked at W3C.

Comment: @AMC: your code, *before* you wrap your `li` elements in a `div` is absolutely fine (assuming no other errors); however *after* wrapping in an `li` element in a `div` your HTML is invalid: the *only* valid child of a `ul`, or `ol` element, is an `li`.

Comment: @DavidThomas I guess I should have been more clear in my example then. I know not to wrap `<li>` in `<div>`, the order in which my code appears is `<div>` then `<ul>` and finally `<li>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

[Live examples of all proposed solutions](http://johnsuarez.com/so/cssNav/index.html)

Working with AMC it was determined that a JavaScript solution would work better given the requirements. All content would appear on one page so the CSS solutions would not work based on my findings. I proposed the simple jQuery code to show a bullet when the link was clicked.

jQuery

```
$(window).load(function(event) {
    $('a').click(function() {
        $('#Nav li').removeClass();
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");                   
    });
});
```

CSS

```
#navcontainer3 ul {
    width: 200px;
    list-style-type:disc;
}

#navcontainer3 ul li {
    color: #ccc;
    float:right;
    clear:right;
}

#navcontainer3 ul li.current {
    color: #000;
}
```

[This page contains examples of all the solutions](http://johnsuarez.com/so/cssNav/index.html) but you'll find the jQuery solution alone at this link: http://jsfiddle.net/jtRws/10/.

---

Interesting problem. Obviously, there are JavaScript solutions, but it looks like you want a pure CSS solution.

#### Solution 0

Hide the other list item bullets by setting the list style color to the background color.

All pages will have the same navigation HTML but each page's `<body>` will have an `id` unique for that page. For example: `<body id="home">`, `<body id="products">`, etc. Then, using some clever CSS, the current page will obtain the specific styling definition (last def below).

```
#navcontainer0 ul {
    width: 200px;
    list-style-type:disc;
}

#navcontainer0 ul li {
    color: #fff;
    float:right;
    clear:right;
}

body#home #homenav0,
body#products #prodnav0 {
    color: #000;
}
```

#### Solution 1

Use `background` to show and hide the bullet image. [Based on this article](http://hicksdesign.co.uk/journal/highlighting-current-page-with-css) I used the following code. [The article explains the technique in greater detail.](http://hicksdesign.co.uk/journal/highlighting-current-page-with-css) Below you'll find the same code as the live example.

CSS

```
#navcontainer ul {
    width: 200px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    text-align:right;
}

#navcontainer ul li a:hover {
    color: #930;
    background: #f5d7b4;
}

body#home a#homenav,
body#products a#prodnav,
body#faq a#faqnav,
body#contact a#connav {
    background:url(bullet.gif) 0 50% no-repeat no-repeat;
    padding-left:15px;
}
```

Products Page

```
<body id="products">
    <div id="navcontainer">
        <ul id="navlist">
            <li><a id="homenav" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a id="prodnav" href="products.html" >Products</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Using Solution 0, I've adapted your code to my site. Currently, the `disc` is showing next to all page options, regardless of which section I'm actually on.

Comment: @AMC, you see it does work in my live examples, right? It might be due to how you have your `<div>` setup [like you mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018079/use-bullet-to-indicate-current-page-in-navigation-menu#comment21250662_15018079). Is there anyway you could show one page's markup? Btw, I tested solution 0 on the latest versions of Chrome, Safari, and IE9.

Comment: Yep, that's precisely why I decided to pursue your solutions. I've taken a bit of my code and put it in jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/s66eV/1/) so you can see what I'm working with. I appreciate your continued efforts.

Comment: My solutions won't work in jsfiddle. Based on your question, I assumed that you have a different page for each nav link. Is that the case? If so, each page's `<body>` will have a unique `id`. Or, do you have only one page and are loading or show/hiding the content? That will require a different solution.

Comment: @AMC, I'll be in the CSS chat room if you have questions: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3840/css

Comment: I have one long, single page with each section given an id anchor.

Comment: can't say thank you enough. 

For future reference, if anyone else needs it, this is the javascript that ended up working like a dream. http://jsfiddle.net/jtRws/10/

Comment: Apparently I can't reward bounty for another 5 hours?? I'll definitely check back and get you those 50pts.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using anchors to navigate through page sections, so the only way I can think of right now is using javascript(jQuery).

I've updated your code example: http://tinyurl.com/a6ypyuz

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want bullets only to current page. So first of all we're goind to eliminate normal bullets.

```
ul {list-style-type:none;}
```

Than i saw that you use id's for content divs on every page. Combining that with atribute selector  here's an example of what you could do:

```
#home li a[href='#home']:before, #about li a[href='#about']:before {
content:"•";pointer-events:none; text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: This looks like the best way to handle this using only css

Comment: I disagree. This answer hyperlinks the list bullet which I doubt the OP wants.

Comment: i made an edit so that pointer has no effect on the bullet. and the style can be changed with text-decoration, color and so on.

Comment: @DanOvidiuBoncut, I don't see a difference when I try it out. Can you post a live example? Edit: I see that the bullet cannot be clicked but the underline is still present.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @earthdesigner answer, if you don't want to add jquery then use this javascript instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/7uxcg/31/

```
window.onload = function() {
    // var nav = document.getElementById('nav');
    var nav = document.getElementsByTagName('NAV')[0].children[0];

    for(c in nav.children) {
        var li = nav.children[c];
        if(li.nodeName == 'LI') {
            li.onclick = function() {
                changeClass(this.children[0].hash);
            }
        }
    }

    function changeClass(cur) {
        var nav = document.getElementsByTagName('NAV')[0].children[0];

        for(c in nav.children) {
            var li = nav.children[c];
            if(li.nodeName == 'LI' && li.children[0].hash == cur)
                li.className = 'active';
            else
                li.className = ''
        }        
    }
};
```